# Problem with editing and adding text files to project

Tags: swift, xcode

This is my code that works perfectly fine when I add someones txt file.

```
   DispatchQueue.global().async { [self] in
                
                    //ovo oznacava level1↓ jer je pocetna vrednost poseda level = 1
        if let levelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "text1", withExtension: "txt"){
        if let levelContents = try? String(contentsOf: levelFileURL){
            var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            lines.shuffle()
            
            for (index,line) in lines.enumerated(){
                let parts = line.components(separatedBy: " — ")
                let answer = parts[0]
              
                let clue = parts [1]
```

But if I try to eddit that txt file or even add my own txt file I always get an error for parts[1] saying: *Thread 2: Fatal error: Index out of range*

example of text file I want to use:

Afghanistan — Kabul
Albania — Tirana
Algeria — Algiers

Comment: What do you mean with someone else and my own file, what is the difference? And edit, how and when?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean if I add similar text file from internet code works well but if i edit that file i get an error I mentioned. Same if I make my own txt file and put it in xcode my code does't work

Comment: I kind of guessed that after I wrote my comment. Is this your own code, I guess not and that the problem is that you don't understand what the code does? What about running this in the debugger or adding some print statements to understand what happens.  And/or read the documentation for `components(separatedBy:)`.

Comment: I've added print(clue) and it successfully printed all countries capitals  but I also get error:Index out of range. If I delete  let clue = parts [1] line code works perfectly without errors @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @PowerPlay When you edited the text file whats the text you added exactly? Because the code is expecting every line it reads from file to have some text - (hyphen) some text format, if you dont follow that it will crash obviously, example `India - Delhi` will be fine other than that if you add text in any other format like `India` or `India Delhi` or `India -`  will fail

Comment: You should print earlier, like `line` and `parts` in the `for` loop. That should give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you guys my code works for now because I've found text file on internet. I will insert a video of me editing only one letter in that file and my code crashes again with same error

Comment: Creating a video is a bit overkill imo, can't you just add a small sample to the question and explain what kind of edit you do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work with the sample file you've given:

```
import Foundation

let levelContents = """
Afghanistan — Kabul
Albania — Tirana
Algeria — Algiers
"""

var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
lines.shuffle()

for (index, line) in lines.enumerated() {
    let parts = line.components(separatedBy: " — ")

    debugPrint(parts)

    let answer = parts[0]
    let clue = parts [1]

    print("answers \(answer), clue: \(clue)")
}
```

Notice in this sample I use `debugPrint` to show me the array of `parts` that gets generated.  You could put a similar line in your code to find out what the `parts` array contains in cases where the code fails.